# Locking down Mediawiki permissions

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to lock down my Mediawiki 1.30 installation so absolutely nobody can read or edit it, as a baseline to start with group permissions. However, nothing seems to work, and I can't understand why.

At the bottom of my LocalSettings.php file I have the following entries:

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
$wgRevokePermissions['user']['edit'] = true;
$wgRevokePermissions['user']['read'] = true;
```

which I believe should mean that nobody can do anything with the wiki. Obviously this isn't my ultimate goal, but it's a baseline I'd like to get to.

As it is, registered users can login and edit the wiki, while anonymous users cannot.

Can anyone explain what the problem is? It seems as thought nothing I change makes a difference, but I'm definitely editing the correct file...

Comment: Those settings look correct (although `$wgRevokePermissions` shouldn't be necessary), so probably your settings file is not getting parsed for reason.

Comment: That's what I thought, but all the DB stuff is in there, and it couldn't work without it...

Comment: Maybe there is a stray `return` somewhere, or those settings get overwritten somewhere else, or maybe some ill-considered extension code changes them... in any case, the problem is not with the snippet you posted.